# r program Creating wordcloud from table

Tags: r

I am trying to find wordcloud with data frame table which has only 1 column. It's something like

```
           USE
     1     sfd 
     2     sfd
     3     Sfd-Detached                          
     4     Sfd-Detached
     5     Sfd-Detached
```

I have used

```
wordcloud(rownames(clean), min.freq=0)  
wordcloud(colnames(clean), min.freq=0)
```

However, wordcloud produced row number when I used rownames and name of my column when I used colname. Is there any way to produce wordcloud with what is actually in my column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reference specific `data.frame` column for `wordcloud` to work without specifying `freq` argument. See `?wordcloud`.

```
wordcloud(clean$USE, min.freq=0)
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.